# Effect of Skewness and data range in machine learning

Tags: feature-engineering

I have a feature for machine learning as follow that skew to the left, and only have number in certain number range (here 0-2000). Will skewness and range of number affect the learning? If yes what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Your problem is addressable by Poisson regression. You may also want to take a look at Censored Poisson regression because your data is right-censored at 2000.

Comment: The best way to fix skewness is to perform a log transformation. Please read [How to deal with Skewed Dataset in Machine Learning?](https://becominghuman.ai/how-to-deal-with-skewed-dataset-in-machine-learning-afd2928011cc) for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, folks would transform the variable. When it is strictly greater than zero, a log transform is usually sufficient. If zero is included, as in your case, one popular alternative is the [box-cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform).